# window.parent is always undefined in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have recently ran into this strange issue, I was trying to reference parent window in an iframe, but somehow window.parent or parent are always undefined.

I got around the problem by using window.top, but this question still haunts me.

Why is window.parent undefined?

This is a .NET web app, if it helps.

**Update**: I would like to add that both parent and child iframes are pointed to the same domain (localhost). As for code, I have tried the following code:

```
if (parent != null)
{
  // do something
}
```

where *do something* never happens, I also tried

```
alert(parent)
```

and

```
alert(window.parent)
```

they always come out as null.

Comment: Tis very strange ideed.  I used parent to get the parent of the iframe many times... perhaps you are loading a page from a different domain in your iframe?

Comment: @bigmattyh: I'm not sure what to show you, except that in my javascript I have if (parent != null) { //do something } and it's never evaluated to be true.

@Zoidberg: thanks for the hint, but it's the same domain. (they're all within http://localhost:1030/ )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Damn, this finally turned out to be a coding error -- somebody accidentally re-defined parent in another function:

```
parent = blah
```

while he should have used

```
var parent = blah
```

Answer (score -2):

Security - where IS window.parent....

also check case of property... js is case sensitive...

Comment: as for "where", do you mena the url? everything is localhost

Comment: this response needs some love. its really not clear what you're trying to say here.